# how to list out all triggers in a particular table OR database?

Tags: sql-server-2005, triggers

how can I list out all triggers on a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select * from sys.triggers
```

Answer (score 2):

The [sys.triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188746(SQL.90).aspx) view contains information about the triggers, you can filter on parent_id if you want just one table. (Get the object id of the table or view with the [OBJECT_ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328(SQL.90).aspx)() function)

[OBJECT_DEFINITION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176090(SQL.90).aspx)() can be used to retrieve the text of the trigger, if required.